# Why iterator.forEachRemaining doesnt remove element in the Consumer lambda?

Tags: lambda, java-8, listiterator

Lets have a look at this example:

```
public class ListIteratorTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add("element1");
        list.add("element2");
        list.add("element3");
        list.add("element4");

        ListIterator<String> iterator = list.listIterator();
    }
}
```

And now, this works fine:

```
    // prints elements out, and then appropriately removes one after another
    while (iterator.hasNext()){
        System.out.println(iterator.next());
        iterator.remove();
    }
```

while this throws an IllegalStateException:

```
        // throws IllegalStateException, why?
        iterator.forEachRemaining(n -> {
            System.out.println(n);
            iterator.remove();
        });
```

My question is short: why?

Comment: Lambda expressions (and of course, method references, too) have the great advantage of creating much more readable or clean code. I tend to use them wherever I get a real benefit - in terms of readability - from them. Your lambda example is not more readable or less readable then the example that does not use a lambda expression. In fact, it has the same number of code lines. So why do you feel, that you must (or should) use lambdas here? In fact ... you detected it ... they make your code somewhat complicated, as you shouldn't use the iterator inside the lambda.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose I am still in progress with learning capabilities of Java8 so I try to use lambdas etc. everywhere I can. I just thought if it is possible and wanted to check it - it had given unexpected results and I didnt know why so asked here; but thanks for explanation of what are lambas actually made for - for simplicity where possible

Answer (score 18, accepted):

<sup>Updated thanks to @studro. See his comment below.</sup>

The [API documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#forEachRemaining-java.util.function.Consumer-) states:

> The behavior of an iterator is unspecified if the underlying collection is modified while the iteration is in progress in any way other than by calling this method.

It seems like the "unspecified behavior" part also applies during this internal iteration.

Granted, the documentation for `forEachRemaining` states that the behavior is equivalent to

```
while (hasNext())
    action.accept(next());
```

and if `action::accept` did in fact call `iterator.remove()` the above snippet should not throw any exception (if `remove` is a supported operation). This might be a documentation bug.

Comment: so then, is it possble to iterate through the list using lambdas (for example iterator.forEachRemaining()) and delete the element after operating on it?

Comment: Sure. You can store the to-be-deleted elements in a separate list, `toDelete`, and after the forEachRemaining has completed, you can use `list.removeAll(toDelete)`. That is however not the idiomatic way to solve it in Java 8. You probably want to use `stream.filter`.

Comment: ... or just `list.removeIf(...)` if you want to modify the list in place in an idiomatic java 8 way.

Comment: @aioobe hm.. lets take a situation where I recieve a list of some objects from my ServiceClass. I want this list to be iterated over and for every element something should be done and then the object should be deleted (so finally the List is destroyed). How are filters useful here?

Comment: Those are two terminal operations, so they shouldn't (can't) be mixed. I would recommend using two separate iterations. One `.forEach` and one `removeIf` (as @AlexisC. points out).

Comment: `In other words, you may not modify the collection inside the callback.`. That is not at all what that doc says. It says you may not modify the collection while iterating via any other method than remove. In the original question, the asker is only modifying using the remove method. If the Java developers had not overridden the default `forEachRemaining()` method on the `Iterator` interface, this would work fine.

Comment: @studro, thanks for bringing this to my attention. I've updated the answer and will investigate a bit further.

Comment: @aioobe I didn't realise you were on the Java dev team. Thanks for looking at this. It's either a documentation or implementation bug. It's a shame that it doesn't work, but I can see why the override was undertaken in ArrayList (for improved performance ie. reduced heap traffic).