# List iterator illegal state exception

Tags: java, list, iterator

There is this class

```
public class IteratorStuff {

    private static final String EMPTY = "";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("success:");
        success(newCollection());
        System.out.println("fail:");
        fail(newCollection());
    }

    private static void fail(Collection<String> myCollection) {
        Iterator<String> iterator = myCollection.iterator();
        iterator.forEachRemaining(new Consumer<String>() {
            public void accept(String s) {
                if (s != EMPTY)
                    System.out.println("string = " + s);
                else
                    iterator.remove();
            }
        });
    }

    private static Collection<String> newCollection() {
        Collection<String> myList = new LinkedList<String>();
        myList.add(EMPTY);
        myList.add("1");
        myList.add("2");
        myList.add("3");
        return myList;
    }

    private static void success(Collection<String> myCollection) {
        Iterator<String> iterator = myCollection.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            String s = iterator.next();
            if (s != EMPTY)
                System.out.println("string = " + s);
            else
                iterator.remove();
        }
    }
}
```

It iterates over a collections of Strings and removes a particular EMPTY String and prints the others. The success(Collection) implementation works fine.

The fail one breaks with an IllegalStateException. However, it is able to get the EMPTY String from the iterator. That suggests that next() must have been called. Also, in the default forEachRemaining implementation

```
default void forEachRemaining(Consumer<? super E> action) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(action);
    while (hasNext())
        action.accept(next());
}
```

next() is called and what ever element is passed to action.accept(). On a side not I also cannot seem to find the implementation of the Iterator returned by LinkedList.

Is this a bug? How can the first element be returned and still cause an IllegalStateException?

Also, this only happens if the first element is the EMPTY String.

Comment: because forEachRemaining is a default method in iterator. really dont see what youre asking...

Comment: I would NOT expect `iterator.remove()` to work in the context of `forEachRemaining` as it is probably not using the Iterator internally.  It works fine in the `success` case because there you _are_ using the iterator and removing the current element.  However, I don't have a doc reference for you so I'm posting this as a comment.  Since `forEachRemaining()` does not specify HOW it iterates, there's no reason for the `Iterator` in your code to be usable.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29210510/why-iterator-foreachremaining-doesnt-remove-element-in-the-consumer-lambda

Comment: @JimGarrison yes, I realize it works fine in success because it is used as intended for a long time now. forEachRemaining, however (at last in default implementation), does call next() and pass result to action.

Comment: @aiguy Both `ArrayList` and `LinkedList` override the default `forEachRemaining` method and, as @Jim Garrison says, they don't use the iterator methods.

Comment: Interesting question. I like questions that don't have immediately obvious answers and make me go look at [GrepCode](http://grepcode.com) :-)

Comment: @aiguy Please read Andreas' answer.  I believe he is actually correct, although I'm not sure this qualifies as a bug... maybe an ambiguity in the specification.  For the benefit of future readers (which is the whole point of StackOverflow) I suggest you unaccept my answer and accept his.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **For future readers: THIS ANSWER IS INCORRECT!**
>
> Even though the asker has accepted this answer as solution to their problem, it may not work [for others or in general]. Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41152317/476) by Andreas for a more thorough analysis of the problem.

If you look at the code for `LinkedList$ListItr` (the `ListIterator` implementation returned by `LinkedList#iterator()`) in GrepCode you'll see that it does not update the iterator itself, it starts from the current element and does the iteration using local variables.

This means that the iterator itself, on which you never called `next()` is invalid.  Even if you did call `next()` prior to entering the loop, it would remove the wrong element(s), and also probably cause `ConcurrentModificationException` as its position is not updated by `forEachRemaining()` and item removal would interfere with the iterator.

`<soapbox>`
For any question about the Java libraries not resolvable from the Javadoc, [GrepCode](http://grepcode.com) is the go-to resource.  Use it.
`</soapbox>`

Comment: What source code are you looking at? The openjdk source doesn't use local variables in `LinkedList$ListItr.forEachRemaining()`. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41152317/5221149).

Comment: Very interesting.... you are correct.  The OP should accept your answer instead for a more thorough analysis.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're using a `LinkedList`, and it has it's own **flawed** implementation of `forEachRemaining()`.

[Source](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/LinkedList.java#l953):

```
public void forEachRemaining(Consumer<? super E> action) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(action);
    while (modCount == expectedModCount && nextIndex < size) {
        action.accept(next.item);
        lastReturned = next;
        next = next.next;
        nextIndex++;
    }
    checkForComodification();
}
```

With the *default* implementation, the `accept()` method wouldn't be called until after `next()` returns.

```
public E next() {
    checkForComodification();
    if (!hasNext())
        throw new NoSuchElementException();

    lastReturned = next;
    next = next.next;
    nextIndex++;
    return lastReturned.item;
}
```

Since `remove()` checks the value of `lastReturned`, that value needs to be set before called `accept()`.

```
public void remove() {
    checkForComodification();
    if (lastReturned == null)
        throw new IllegalStateException();

    Node<E> lastNext = lastReturned.next;
    unlink(lastReturned);
    if (next == lastReturned)
        next = lastNext;
    else
        nextIndex--;
    lastReturned = null;
    expectedModCount++;
}
```

As already mentioned, the `forEachRemaining()` implementation is **bugged**. It should be:

```
public void forEachRemaining(Consumer<? super E> action) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(action);
    while (modCount == expectedModCount && nextIndex < size) {
        lastReturned = next;
        next = next.next;
        nextIndex++;
        action.accept(lastReturned.item);
    }
    checkForComodification();
}
```

File a bug!

---

**Update**

[`ArrayList$Itr.forEachRemaining()`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java#l862) has a similar problem, were `cursor` and `lastRet` is not set during iteration, so although javadoc of `forEachRemaining()` doesn't explicitly say you cannot use `Iterator.remove()` or `ListIterator.add()`, the current implementations obviously didn't expect that you would.

They don't even fail or guard in a consistent manner, so they are not consistent with normal fail-fast policy.

So perhaps filing a bug for documentation and/or fail fast logic would be more appropriate.

Comment: Does it violate the iterator contract, though? The iterator interface doesn't specify that it's valid to access the iterator during the `forEachRemaining` method. Provided the state of the iterator is consistent by the time `forEachRemaining` returns, I would say it doesn't qualify as a bug.

Comment: @Sam It also doesn't say that you cannot, and given that a simple reordering of the code will fix the problem, I'd say it's an unintentional error. If not, why even update `lastReturned` at all? Right now, it fails if you try to remove the *first* element, but works for any other element.

Comment: `lastReturned` has to be updated either way to indicate that the iterator has been consumed.

Comment: I think I agree, though. Always better to make things simpler where possible. I wonder if it has an impact on any of the other iterator methods, though. Since this is a list iterator, what if one were to call `add` during the `forEachRemaining`? Or `previous`?

Comment: @Sam `lastReturned` doesn't indicate whether the iterator has been consumed. It just hold a iterator position reference to the last element returned by `next()`, so `remove()` can remove it. It is `null` before the first call to `next()` and after a call to `remove()`. It has nothing to do with at-end logic for the iterator.

Comment: You're right, I misread the code.

Comment: if you call previous I suspect youll end up in an infinite loop. would be best if it doesnt work. :)

Comment: @aiguy Wouldn't that always be the case, calling `previous()` and `next()` in a loop would loop forever? That has nothing to do with `forEachRemaining()`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be -
you are working on iterator and concurrently modifying it.

```
private static void fail(Collection<String> myCollection) {
    Iterator<String> iterator = myCollection.iterator();
    iterator.forEachRemaining(new Consumer<String>() {
        public void accept(String s) {
            if (s != EMPTY)
                System.out.println("string = " + s);
            else
                iterator.remove();
        }
    });
}
```

you are calling forEachRemaining method using iterator object and inside that you are also removing the object from same iterator.

Comment: Cannot comment so posted in the answer section.

Comment: This is a good point. The body of the `Consumer` method should be considered as a single operation. For the duration of that operation, the state of the iterator is undefined. The iterator is quite within its rights to get upset if you try to call other methods on it while the consumer method is running.

Comment: in that case an iteration of your normal while hasNext loop should be considered a single operation? Im not sure this makes sense.